# Parse field name which contain dot character with $parse

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider I have object which has a field that contains dot character and I want to parse it with `$parse` ,

For example , the follow code logs `undefined` -

```
 var getter = $parse('IhaveDot.here');
 var context = {"IhaveDot.here":'The point value'};
 scope.name = getter(context);
 console.log(scope.name); // logs 'undefined'
```

how to make it to logs the field value - e.g - `The point value` ?

```js
var myAppModule = angular.module('myAppModule', []).
  directive('n',function($parse){
   return {
    restrict: 'E', 
    link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
     var getter = $parse('IhaveDot.here');
     var context = {"IhaveDot.here":'The point value'};
     scope.name = getter(context);
     console.log(scope.name);
    }
   }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<n></n>
```

Comment: var context = { IhaveDot: { here: 'The point value' }};

Comment: No , I want this field name entire with that dot - "IhaveDot.here"

Comment: Is context supposed to be valid JSON?

Comment: @Pieter21 . Yes it does , according to this - http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I also checked with JSON lint, and needed double quotes, not on the field but on the value. (I only checked {"IhaveDot.here":'The point value'};)

Comment: I made an example that matches more your request (2.Version). Hope this helps

Comment: If you store the value on an object, you can access it as a property - `foo['IhaveDot.here']`. But if its directly on context, that is probably not possible (at least I don't know how to refer to the context itself in the expression... maybe `this` will work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service **$parse** works with dots so in regular way you have to define context in this fashion:

```
var getter = $parse('user.name');
var context = {user:{name:'angular'}};

console.log(getter(context)); //  angular
```

Another possibility to override extisting services of angular. Something like this:

**1.Version**

```
var myParseapp = angular.module('parsemodule', [])

myParseapp.factory('$myparse', function($parse) {

    var body = angular.element(document.body);
    var parse = {};

    parse.parse = function (context, exp) {

        var parts = exp.split('.');
        var obj = context;

        for(var p=0;p < parts.length;p++){
            var getter = $parse(parts[p]);
            obj = getter(obj);
        }

        return obj;
    };

    return parse;

});
```

And include your module into the actual app-module:

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['parsemodule']);

testApp.controller('testController', function($scope, $myparse) {

    var context = {name:'jack'};
    var exp = 'name';

    console.log($myparse.parse(context,exp)); // jack

    var context = {user:{name:'angular'}};
    var exp = 'user.name';

    console.log($myparse.parse(context,exp)); // angular

    context = {user:{name:{job:'programmer'}}};
    exp = 'user.name.job';

    console.log($myparse.parse(context,exp)); // programmer

});
```

**2.Version**

Here is a version that matches your request:

```
var myParseapp = angular.module('parsemodule', [])

myParseapp.factory('$myparse', function($parse) {

    var body = angular.element(document.body);
    var parse = {};

    parse.parse = function (context, exp) {

        context = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(context)); // deep copy

        var oldPropName = Object.keys(context)[0];

        if(oldPropName.indexOf('.') != -1) {

            context[oldPropName.replace(/[.]/g, '_')] = context[oldPropName];

            delete context[oldPropName];

        }

        var obj = context;
        var getter = $parse(exp.replace(/[.]/g,'_'));
        obj = getter(obj);

        return obj;
    };

    return parse;

});
```

And insert it ones more into your actual-app:

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['parsemodule']);

testApp.controller('testController', function($scope, $myparse) {

    var context = {name:'jack'};
    var exp = 'name';

    console.log($myparse.parse(context,exp)); // jack

    var context = {'user.name':'angular'};
    var exp = 'user.name';

    console.log($myparse.parse(context,exp)); // angular

    context = {'user.name.job':'programmer'};
    exp = 'user.name.job';

    console.log($myparse.parse(context,exp)); // programmer

    exp = 'IhaveDot.here';
    context = {"IhaveDot.here":'The point value'};

    console.log($myparse.parse(context,exp)); // The point value

});
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can refer to the context via `this` (undocumented feature). So the simplest approach would be:

```
var getter = $parse("this['IhaveDot.here']");
var context = {"IhaveDot.here":'The point value'};
console.log(getter(context));  // => The point value
```

Check [the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/p8z4esoT0ICS5SLhKB18?p=preview).